# IIS - two sites under one domain - best way to achieve this?

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, subdomain, virtual-directory

I read a lot articles and questions here on stackoverflow.
But I am not quite sure which solution fits my needs.

I have a two sites in IIS.
https://example.com
and
https://career.example.com

Both have different physical paths on the same server. Both use different CMS and are websites.

I want the subdomain site to be accessed under a subolder instead:
https://example.com/career/

The subfolders also should be available under the new path.

e.g.
https://career.example.com/job1
should be
https://example.com/career/job1

The solutions go from simple redirects in the site of the subdomain, to virtual directories, or changing bindings and adding new ones under the main domain....

I am not sure which way to go.

Do you recommend a solution?

Comment: Study what is reverse proxy, and that's simply the standard way to go now. Make no change on other parts please, as that's just waste of your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the subdomain site to be accessed under a subolder instead, that is, when you go to the URL like https://example.com/career/job1 in the browser address bar, the content of the webpage you actually access is https:/ /career.example.com/job1. Please correct me if I understand wrong.

To achieve this, you need to use Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite and Application Request Routing. The specific implementation steps are as follows:

1. You need to enable reverse proxy in IIS. If you have not installed the ARR module, you need to download and install it first.

[image]

2. Then you need to add reverse proxy rewrite rules under https://example.com site. The rule in web.config as follow:

[image]

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) to learn more about Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite and ARR.

Comment: I get a weird phenomenon.
here are my current rules. because yours were not working.

[Rules](https://imgur.com/a/RITcRTr)

If I open example.com/career 
the url in the browser stays, the content of the other website is loaded...but without CSS and images

If I browse example.com/career/subfolder
the url in the browser changes to 
career.example.com/subfolder

and everything works.

- It seems that the main url gets the routing right, but there are still something missing...outbound rules?

And the subfolders redirect completely to the other website. 

What is going on?

Comment: According to your rules, when you open example.com/career, the URL matches the first rule, and after rewriting it will return the content of https://career.example.com/. At this point, the default file in the root directory of the subdomain's website should be displayed.
If you directly access https://career.example.com/ in your browser, can the page be displayed normally?

Comment: If I directly access career.example.com the site works fine. Maybe it is a problem, because on the career.example.com site are also URL rewrites defined.

Comment: You can try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules